# Get-Process output value if it it does not find the process specified

Tags: powershell, outlook

What is the `Get-Process` output value if it does not find a process specified? For example, I am checking if Outlook is closed and if it is, I back a PST file. Here is my code:

```
$source = "C:\Users\----\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Outlook.pst"
$destination = "\\----\users\----\outlook"

$isOutlookOpen = Get-Process outlook*
$isOutlookOpen
if($isOutlookOpen = $true){
    # Outlook is already closed:
    Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination
    $messageParameters = @{
        Subject = "Daily Outlook Backup Report computer"
        Body = "Outlook was closed. Backup was complete."
        From = "---"
        To = "---"
        SmtpServer = "---"
        Port = ---
    }
    Send-MailMessage @messageParameters -BodyAsHtml
} else {
    $messageParameters = @{
        Subject = "Daily Outlook Backup Report computer"
        Body = "Outlook was not closed. Backup was not initiated."
        From = "---"
        To = "---"
        SmtpServer = "---"
        Port = ---
    }
    Send-MailMessage @messageParameters -BodyAsHtml
}
```

It always goes to the `else` statement.

Comment: A side note, you should also probably check for open Skype / Lync as these can lock the archive too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an [assignment operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847875.aspx) (`=`) in the condition, so it will always evaluate to `$true`. The equality [comparison operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) in PowerShell is `-eq`.

With that said, you don't need an operator there in the first place. [`Get-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx) returns a list of [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects (or `$null` if no matching process is found). You can use the value of the variable `$isOutlookOpen` like a boolean value, because PowerShell will [interpret](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/) a non-empty array as a boolean value `$true` and `$null` as a boolean value `$false`.

This should work:

```
$isOutlookOpen = Get-Process outlook*
if($isOutlookOpen) {
    # ...
} else {
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are checking if something is $true when it's value would be the details of the process:

```
$isOutlookOpen = Get-Process outlook*
$isOutlookOpen
if($isOutlookOpen = $true){
```

Even if it did give a true or false response you are actually assigning a value of $true in your if statement. It should be:

```
if ($isOutlookOpen -eq $true)
```

A better way to do it would be to put it in a try and catch block:

```
try {
 get-process outlook* -errorAction stop
}
catch {
 write-host "Outlook not running..."
}
```